# Magento How to display the search results from search query in a custom page

Tags: magento

In magento,

I would like to display the products retrieved from the search query in a custom pages.
By default these products are displaying in `catalogsearch/result/?q="some text"`.
I would like to restrict this redirection and these search results have to be displayed on my custom pages (say `index.php` itself).

Can any one provide me the solution for this?

Thanks in advance
Mani

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
\app\design\frontend\default\your theme\layout/catalogsearch.xml
```

in line no 52:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
```

change into:

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/{YOUR PHTML FILE}</template></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via jQuery ajax request.

Onclick operation over the search button send the request to

```
catalogsearch/result/?q="some text"
```

You need to replace the entire html because on search we are getting entire magento search page(Not feasible)

OR

Create a custom module and override **catalogsearch.xml** remove header footer left and right navigation section and set body only.

This will do the job!!!  Its working for me.

NOTE:CUSTOM MODULE DEVELOPED CAN BE USED TO OVERRIDE BLOCK,CONTROLLER ACTION AND ALSO WE CAN CHANGE AS PER REQUIREMENT